# My issue is "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting an error from this:

```
((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), routeData));
```

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

The full code as given below.

```
 private void RedirectToControllers(string control, string action, bool redirectCheck = false)
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = control;
            routeData.Values["action"] = action;
            IController controller = null;
            if (control == Constants.Alerts)
            {
                controller = new AlertsController();
            }
            else if (control == Constants.Account)
            {
                controller = new AccountController();
            }

            if (controller != null)
            {
                if (redirectCheck)
                {
                   ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), routeData));
                   // new RedirectResult(Constants.LoginUrl, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    string returnUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation == null)
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(string.Format("/{0}/{1}?" + returnUrl, ControllerHelper.Controller.ACCOUNT, ControllerHelper.Controller.Action.ACCOUNT_LOGIN));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that something in your application is altering the `Response.Headers` collection and then attempting to set the status code. This is not being done in the code block that you have provided, but is occurring elsewhere in your application.

The fix is to clear the request before passing it onto your controller. You can do that by calling `Response.Clear()`.

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
httpContext.Response.Clear();
((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData));
```

You should review your application though to make sure that this is the right course of action, as this will clear any other response settings that may be required for your application to run properly.

Comment: I am getting error for the same code. An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: Issues resolved using if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation == null)
                    {                       
                    }